# Why is the file empty after writing to it with bufio.Writer?

Tags: go

```golang
file, err := os.OpenFile("filename.db", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()
res := 0
writer := bufio.NewWriter(file)
for _, data := range manager {
    bin, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    res++
    if debug {
        log.Println(res)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", bin)
    _, err = writer.Write(bin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    _, _ = writer.WriteRune('\n')
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rfK6c4Gx8uR)
[full code](https://pastebin.com/yFDE2fJ9)

The file `filename.db` is created (if didn't exist), but ...is empty...
Why could this happen?
Why is the file empty?
I tried this both on my home pc and a linux server
And in both cases it's empty

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#example-Writer `w.Flush() // Don't forget to flush!`

Comment: In another go project I could successfully appendto the file in the same wayand without flushing. So what does it do and why does This not work without it?

Comment: the other project has a bug!  go fix it ! As to why it worked, it might just be that you wrote sufficient to trigger internal flushing and somehow did not need a final flush. Under some conditions bufio.Writer might decide not to buffer https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/bufio/bufio.go;l=639  or to flush https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/bufio/bufio.go;l=643 but you must always apply a final flush

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion from comment using `writer.Flush` results in foo and bar values being written in to the document filename.db.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Valuable struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

var debug = true
var manager []Valuable

func main() {
    manager = append(manager, Valuable{"foo"}, Valuable{"bar"})

    file, err := os.OpenFile("filename.db", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    res := 0
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()
    for _, data := range manager {
        bin, err := json.Marshal(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        res++
        if debug {
            log.Println(res)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", bin)
        _, err = writer.Write(bin)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        _, _ = writer.WriteRune('\n')
        
    }
}
```

Comment: should it no flush only once, with a defer ? flushing at each iteration kind of cancel the speed improvements provided by bufio.Writer

Comment: @mh-cbon modified

Comment: i have updated again to demonstrate idiomatic code, ie defer flushing right after new. As a reminder to a beginner reading this code defer is LIFO https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/13